# Was Kestrel present in .NET Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

Was Kestrel present in .NET Framework or was it developed specifically for the ASP.NET Core?

I was not able to find an answer to this question by just googling, so I decided to ask it here. I need it because I am intended to work with the ASP.NET Core and would like to know the history of development better, because knowing it allows to better understand the decisions made by developers.

Comment: No, the kestrel was not there in .NET Framework. It born with the origin of ASP.NET Core

Comment: @AnkushJain, thank you for the comment. Should I remove the question now, since I know an answer?

Comment: No. @Ankush Jain should post his comment as an answer and provide an source. Then, you can accept the answer.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha In case it matters, [What is Kestrel Web Server? How It Works, Benefits, and More](https://stackify.com/what-is-kestrel-web-server/) says "Since Kestrel is not a fully-featured web server, you should run it behind IIS or NGINX. It was designed to make ASP.NET as fast as possible but is limited in its ability to manage security and serve static files."

Comment: @AndrewMorton, thank you a lot. I will read it. By the way if someone is interested to learn about Kestrel from the ASP.NET Core perspective, then I can recommend the `ASP.NET Core in Action` book. I am going through it right now. Though it skips the parts which states explicitly that `ASP.NET Framework` does not have the Kestrel.

Answer (score 0):

In order to give an official answer to this question, I copy here comments from @AnkushJain and @andrew-morton:

Kestrel is not available for .NET Framework. It is born with the origin of ASP.NET Core.

[In addition] since Kestrel is not a fully-featured web server, you should run it behind IIS or NGINX. It was designed to make ASP.NET as fast as possible but is limited in its ability to manage security and serve static files.